# Splitting CSV cells using Python

Tags: python, csv, merge, split

I am working with a csv file that is broken down like the list below.

```
FromAddress    ToAddress        CCaddress              bccaddress        datetext
mary.warner    tim.jim,c.koe,   shannon.m, marcus.p    jim.r, kim.t,    fri, Aug10
```

and it needs to look like

```
FromAddress    ToAddress        CCaddress              bccaddress        datetext
mary.warner    tim.jim          shannon.m              jim.r            fri, Aug10
mary.warner    tim.jim          marcus.p               jim.r            fri, Aug10
```

and so on.

Any possible suggestions. I have looked at a few on here but none have worked on Python for me.

Comment: Is that the actual format of the file?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried parsing the csv with a suitable library then rebuilding the string to your specifications?

```
import csv
import sys

f = open(sys.argv[1], 'rt')
try:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  for row in reader:
    #Assemble/Assign Desired Output Here
finally:
  f.close()
```

Comment: Still pretty new and Python is erroring out when I put f=open(sys.argv[1], 'rt'). Am I supposed to open the file within before that statement.

Comment: what is the error? That code is expecting you to provide the filename as input to the script.